# how to center instead of left align divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to horizontally center these divs but they are stacking on top of each other and then left aligning.

How can I have them horizontally aligned center so they look like this:

[image]

```css
.logos{
    margin-left: -32px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.logos ul li{
    float: center;
    width: 210px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #86a7cb;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 32px;
    
}
.logos ul li a{
     display: inline;
     border: 1px solid #86a7cb;
}
.logos ul li img{
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width:99%;
    height: auto;
    horizontal-align: middle;
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid #86a7cb;
}
```

```html
<div class="logos ul">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">My Item 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">My Item 2</a>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your markup inside a `div` and make that `div` a flexbox and add `justify-content : center` to it. Also, add `float : left` to `.logos ul` to ensure they are side to side. See :-

```css
#wrapper{
  display : flex;
  justify-content : center;
}
.logos{
    margin-left: -32px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.logos ul li{
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #86a7cb;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 32px;
    
}
.logos ul li a{
     display: inline;
     border: 1px solid #86a7cb;
}
.logos ul li img{
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width:99%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid #86a7cb;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="logos ul">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">My Item 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">My Item 2</a>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

ALSO, if you want the li elements to spread evenly, horizontally across the ul element, try this:

```
    ul{
    text-align: justify;
    width: 300px;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
   }

ul:after{
    content: '';
    width: 100%; 
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Check out the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0zokhm3w/

Comment: PS: This is the dopest answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Center aligning list](http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/EPJKxr)

The trick is to apply `display:inline-block;` to list elements and apply `text-align:center;`to outer div.